# Expo start react native

Tags: react-native

**How can I solve this after run expo start react native app?*

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/var/www/html/HEETPROJECTS/FishFarmingApp/node_modules/wonka'
at FSWatcher. (node:internal/fs/watchers:247:19)
at Object.watch (node:fs:2304:36)
at NodeWatcher._watchdir (/var/www/html/HEETPROJECTS/FishFarmingApp/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:145:24)
at /var/www/html/HEETPROJECTS/FishFarmingApp/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:47:14
at Walker. (/var/www/html/HEETPROJECTS/FishFarmingApp/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/common.js:135:31)
at Walker.emit (node:events:512:28)
at /var/www/html/HEETPROJECTS/FishFarmingApp/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:180:23)